# set post data python apache

Tags: python, apache, post, mod-python

I am trying to, for a login script, set a session ID using POST in python on apache. However, there doesn't appear to be any method to doing it as far as I can see other than just doing a redirect. Also, now that I have a session ID, I can use any method to set a session ID (POST seemed the most obvious). I would also like for it to work between tabs. Cookies seems like it might be a better option, though it would probably take more effort to implement. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have been trying to set the HTTP headers, specifically the set-cookie one. They don't appear to do anything, though. I was trying this:
`code1<meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="w3scookie=myContent;expires=Sun, 30 Dec 2012 12:00:00 GMT; path=http://www.w3schools.com">`code`
firebug reports that the cookie has been set, however I don't know how to retrieve it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out apache has a cookie module.

```
from mod_python import Cookie
ID = Cookie.get_cookie(req, 'ID')
if ID:
    ID.expires = time.time() + 60*120
    Cookie.add_cookie(req, ID)
    ID = ID.value
else:
    ID = None
```